# How to create a custom EL resolver?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I might be missing the right keywords when searching for this but can anyone please point me to a guide or explain a simple way of creating a custom EL resolver?

Let me explain:

I would like to use the following inside a XHTML tag

```
value="#{images['bonusCheck.png']}"
```

Where this is treated in the same way a ResourceBundle would be treated. I.e.:

Calling something like:

```
protected Object handleGetObject(String key)
```

Ideally I would like to have this format for the XHTML part (requirement) and not use a Bean.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why can't u just use ResourceBundle with a properties file for it? you could also always do something like this `#{imageBean.handleGetObject('bonusCheck.png')}`.

Comment: I might misunderstood your question. For images, css, and js you just need to place your resources under the \resources  folder (same level of \WEB-INF) and you can access it directly... why to make a custom handler?

Comment: @noone Thanks for your input. I wouldn't like to maintain resource files so I have a map with the values I want created dynamically and when I have a value like that I would like to get the value from my map.

Comment: @Yamada the built-in mechanism of JSF doesn't suit my needs. I'm trying to implement localization of images and using library/resources doesn't provide me a fallback mechanism. For instance, if the fr_CA image is not present it doesn't get the fr image, it gets the resources general image, which might be in english. I'm trying to implement on my own but I would like this to be transparent for the developer using it. So he would say images['key'] and the getObject would get the right image based on the locale, whilst providing the right behavior (fallback support).